# migrate stopped mariadb server to new one

Tags: freebsd, mariadb, truenas

Hi I'm running a freenas system where I have two jails. One jail is broken in a way that I cannot start the mariadb server anymore due to userland and kernel version mismatch. So I created a new jail where I installed the mariadb server. Now I want to migrate the old mariadb instance with all the data and settings to the new one.
All instructions I can find refer to a running source instance where the data is dumped and then moved to the new instance. 
How can I migrate the data with a stopped mariadb server?
I still have shell access to the jail that is the source server.

Comment: You can just copy all of the data files.

Comment: And will not forget to change files permissions by command `chmod -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: I found some files in `var/db/mysql` some have the names of my databases, but what files do I need for the user settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I copied everything fro var/db/mysql on the old server to var/db/mysql on the new server and changed the rights like already mentioned.

Everything works fine again.